# Index seek or fetch on each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looping through an array. Some elements in the array are empty and indicate a new group or set of rows thereafter. I'd like assistance with iteration control so my code is a bit cleaner. Here is what I have.

```
xls = SimpleXlsxReader.open(xls_file.path)
rows = xls.sheets.first.rows
g = false
holdThis = Array.new

# Iterate XLSX content
rows.each do |row|

    # An empty row mean new set
    if row[0].present?
        g = true
        next
    end

    # Capture the set information
    if g
        holdThis = row
        g = false
        next
    end

    # Do stuff with row and holdThis
end
```

This works, but isn't very clean. Does Ruby have some equivalent to a seek or fetch method that I can call from inside the each loop (or another kind of loop)?

Here is a pseudocode version of what I'm looking for: a method that can seek the each loop to the next iteration and overwrite the row variable. Is there a way to do this in Ruby?

```
xls = SimpleXlsxReader.open(xls_file.path)
rows = xls.sheets.first.rows
holdThis = Array.new

# Iterate XLSX content
rows.each do |row|

    # An empty row mean new group
    if row[0].present?
        row = each.nextRow #Pseudocode
        holdThis = row
        row = each.nextRow #Pseudocode
    end

    # Do stuff with row and holdThis
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby does have a [fetch](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/fetch) method that you can use to grab the elment by doing current index + 1.

Comment: Not quite what I had in mind. I need that each loop seeking to the next iteration when I call on it. In my pseudocode example, the each.nextRow returns the next row AND tells the each loop that its index has incremented by one. That way, I can effectively skip a row (or use certain rows for certain things) if conditions are met without using "next."